# Including files with php include function not working on my system

Tags: php, function, include

I was trying to include a php file with the code

```
include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/inc/file.php";
```

The error i was getting is

```
Warning: include() [function include]: unable to access C:/wamp/www/inc/file.php on line 6
Warning include(C:/...... Failed to open stream no error.
```

And i tried to use require_once; the error was the same my php version is 5.2

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, it is a legitimate question...  Even though it's pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/file.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/file.php';
```

Comment: Do not rely on $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] because DocumentRoot in httpd.conf Can not be set

Answer (score 0):

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/inc);
include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/inc/file.php";
```